# Unity create straight roads made of road parts in editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, architecture, editor

If there are experienced people reading my question on weekends here, please tell me.

I have cities, I want to make roads between them. The distance between cities can be different. A road consists of small parts (see pic:[cities connected with a road](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qnWk.jpg)
), which are copied several times. Each road should know cities it is connected with. On cities there is a component `City`, on the roads component `Road`.

In general, I do not need to be able to build roads in-game. The main thing for me is to make able the editor connecting cities.

Please, save me! If I continue creating and connecting all the roads (between ~50 cities) manually I will get sick.

Comment: Create a script that takes 2 transforms, it then calculates the distance between these 2 transforms, then using the distance and the dimensions of the road, have it calculate the number of pieces and place them for you.

Comment: Look into Unity Editor Scripting. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Osf1LUFGSvg&list=PL4CCSwmU04MiCnps1DRmwIEEH7gP9X3qq) is pretty a good tutorial.

Comment: @Eddge Could you please explain more on the architecture of the solution? I want to automate road connecting process (connecting transform should also be automated), but according to you comment, it is a lot of manual work.

Comment: @Iggy 
I am very new in Unity scripting and am very glad to get some help from experts. I have just watched the video, but it is about procedural object generation. I am sorry that I am not as clear as it would be sufficient.

Comment: I would watch some beginner tutorials if I were you.  Procedural generation is a way to automate tasks for you, so making the road go from point A to point B, without manually having to place the road would require a procedural process.  What I told you above is the math required to create this procedural process. if done correctly it will vastly increase your productivity.  Using the 2 resources given to you try and do it, and show us what you tried.  Depending on the scale of your project it can reduce your "Manual" work drastically.

Comment: @Eddge I am sorry. I've just understood what you mean. 
In my imagination it was like this: I put a road object on the scene, it is somehow getting connected to a city and I use drag&drop to connect to another city. 

P.S. How can I move cities if roads are procedural generated?

Comment: @kavehecox every time you move a city you have to regenerate all the roads. I'd recommend you instantiate all roads inside a special gameobject, which acts as the root of all roads. When you regenerate you destroy it, and create a new one.

Comment: @Iggy could you please show me a simple example of a script to instantiate a prefab and change its fields? I will accept this as an answer I have watched these videos you sent and created a window, but stuck with instantiating objects from there.